# How to use simultaneously 2 lan adapters?

Tags: java, networking

I have following task, would you suggest, whether (and how if yes) it is possible to solve it:

A computer has 2 LAN adapters; each one is connected to different network provider.
Some information must be sent via first one and some information via second one.

Is it possible somehow to specify which adapter to use by initialization of a connection?

Comment: This is not a superuser question in my view as the java tag implies that it's a java programming question

Comment: @awoodland: I agree, but your suggested reasoning seems odd. Arbitrary questions cannot be made into a programming question by specifying the java tag, you know :)

Comment: @sehe - I was originally going to ask what language they were using until I realised that I already knew what the answer would be from the tags. It ought to be in the body of the question somewhere clearer though, I agree.

Comment: Why do you need different data to go via different NICs? If it is so that different hosts can be reached then this should be achievable by configuring the machine's routing.

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic, it seems to be a (poorly composed) "how do I bind a socket to an interface?" question, which would be on topic.

Comment: Sorry, I've not mentioned it explicitly, but it I really wanted to know, how to implement such possibility using Java. Thank a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java you can use the [`NetworkInterface`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html) class, in conjunction with [`Socket.bind()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#bind%28java.net.SocketAddress%29) to specify what interface to bind to.

Example, taken from [this reference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/definition.html):

```
NetworkInterface nif = NetworkInterface.getByName("bge0");
Enumeration nifAddresses = nif.getInetAddresses();

Socket soc = new java.net.Socket();
soc.bind(nifAddresses.nextElement());
soc.connect(new InetSocketAddress(address, port));
```

Then by setting up two sockets, one per interface you can use both simultaneously.

The other way to solve this problem though is with [interface bonding](https://superuser.com/questions/248621/in-simple-words-what-is-channel-bonding), which is a configuration issue (e.g. [on Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/172398/bonding-2-or-more-gigabyte-nic-together-to-get-2gbps-performance-between-1-server)) and presents two physical interfaces as one virtual interface. (Bonding is the exact opposite of specifying which interface to use when creating a socket, but *isn't* a programming issue though)